# maven-ear-plugin not resolving dependencies

Tags: java, maven, ear

I'm trying to create an ear file using the maven plugin but it's failing on the ear project pom. I've been staring at this for hours and can't figure it out. I'm using eclipse so all my projects including the parent are in the same directory.

My parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${traintrack-version}</version>
    <name>traintrack-parent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <traintrack-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</traintrack-version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>../traintrack-core</module>
        <module>../traintrack-web</module>
        <module>../traintrack-services-authentication</module>
        <module>../traintrack-ear</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

My ear pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
        <artifactId>traintrack-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${traintrack-version}</version>
        <relativePath>../traintrack-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-ear</artifactId>
    <name>traintrack-ear</name>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>${traintrack-version}</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                    <displayName>traintrack-ear</displayName>
                    <modules>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>com.tracktrack</groupId>
                            <artifactId>traintrack-core</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                            <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                        </jarModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.tracktrack</groupId>
                            <artifactId>traintrack-web</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/TrainTrack</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>com.tracktrack</groupId>
                            <artifactId>traintrack-services-authentication</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                            <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                        </jarModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
            <artifactId>traintrack-web</artifactId>
            <version>${traintrack-version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
            <artifactId>traintrack-core</artifactId>
            <version>${traintrack-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
            <artifactId>traintrack-services-authentication</artifactId>
            <version>${traintrack-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and my module pom.xmls begin like the following

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-parent</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../traintrack-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>${traintrack-version}</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
<artifactId>traintrack-core</artifactId>
<version>${traintrack-version}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I get the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.10:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project traintrack-ear: Artifact[jar:com.tracktrack:traintrack-core] is not a dependency of the project.
```

I've been playing around with the dependencies and I found that I get the same error when I remove the dependencies section in the ear pom.xml. It's always the first module listed in the ear that throws the error, and all of them do.

It's probably a silly mistake somewhere but I just can't spot it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in the configuration of `maven-ear-plugin`. `groupId` of `traintrack-core` should be `com.traintrack`, not `com.tracktrack`

So, instead this:

```
<jarModule>
    <groupId>com.tracktrack</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-core</artifactId>
    <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
    <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
</jarModule>
```

Use this:

```
<jarModule>
    <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-core</artifactId>
    <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
    <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
</jarModule>
```

**EDIT:**

The same should be done for `traintrack-web` and `traintrack-services-authentication`.

---

A few tips not related with problem:

- `jar` is the [default](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) packaging, no need to declare it
- `compile` is the [default](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) scope, no need to declare it

A few tips not **directly** related with problem:

- When using modules, is not mandatory to declare the `groupId` in sub modules. You can remove `groupId` from sub modules (such as `traintrack-core`) and keeps running =)
- You can avoid errors like yours using `${project.groupId}` when you're using maven modules and `groupId` are same to all modules/projects, as well as the dependency `groupId` is same of the project

E.g:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-core</artifactId>
    <version>${traintrack-version}</version>
</dependency>

<jarModule>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-core</artifactId>
    <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
    <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
</jarModule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours looking at this and just couldn't see the typo. Thanks also for the tips, I'll definitely take them into account.